# How can I create a custom m2m table in Entity Framework Code-First

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hopefully this is relatively straighforward, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around doing it.

I have one POCO like this:

```
public class TigerTrailRequiredBadge
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TigerTrailRequiredBadgeSubRequirement> TigerTrailRequiredBadgeSubRequirements { get; set; }
}
```

and a very similar one like this:

```
public class TigerTrailElectiveBadge
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Requirement { get; set; }
}
```

These two poco's are tables that will have just a bunch of lookup data. They are lists of requirements for the badges. What I need now is a table to keep track of a persons progress in completing the badges. So I have a root User object that has an object property like this:

```
public class Youth
{
    ...
    public virtual YouthCubRequirementsTracker YouthCubRequirementsTracker { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

That poco looks like this:

```
public class YouthCubRequirementsTracker
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool TigerTrailDone { get; set; }
    public virtual TigerTrailChecklist TigerTrailChecklist { get; set; }
    ...more 'Trail' Checklists ...
}
```

Which brings me to the poco I can't quite figure out: TigerTrailChecklist:

```
public class TigerTrailChecklist
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<TigerTrailRequiredBadge> RequiredBadges { get; set; }
    public List<TigerTrailElectiveBadge> ElectiveBadges { get; set; }
}
```

I want the tiger trail checklist to show this kind of data (pseudo-sql result)

```
Id      FK_ReqBadgeId      FK_ElectiveBadgeID      Complete      CompleteDate
1       42                 null                    true          11-12-13
2       null               13                      true          11-12-14
```

SO, a few questions:

1. Is this a good approach for what I am trying to accomplish?
2. How can I accomplish the result I am looking for via code first?
3. are there any pitfalls I will see as I go along this path? This is just one part of the YouthRequirementTracker class, altogether there are four 'trails', so 4 lookup tables to join to a user (with a table hop or two between)

Comment: Looks fine to me ? The only potential issue I see is that you must access the table to get your data. How fast do you need the data? If its a realtime application like an online game you may want to load the data for a given user before its needed into some local variable.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of pointers:

1. You don't need to annotate your POCO Id properties the `[Key]` and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attributes.  Entity Framework will by convention treat the Id column as a primary key and automatically assign its value during runtime.
2. As far as I can see, there is no many-to-many relationship defined between your POCO's. (I might be wrong but please point out where it is then).
3. Consider making your classes more generic or using abstractions - you don't need to repeat your code for all four trails as it will increase the amount of code you will have to maintain.  Why not have just one lookup table with an additional column for trail name (or better, create a seperate table for trails and just reference the corresponding entry)?